# VARCHAR(MAX) versus VARCHAR(n) in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, types

Similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166371/varcharmax-versus-varcharn-in-ms-sql-server-closed), but for Oracle.

Why would I not always want to choose VARCHAR(MAX)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because it doesn't work in Oracle!  You *could* declare all columns as VARCHAR2(4000) if you wanted, but it isn't recommended by any means.  There will be no difference in storage or performance of the database, but:

- you lose a constraint on the sensible values that can be stored in the column
- some client applications will allocate 4000 bytes of memory to receive data from the column when (say) 10 is all it will ever contain.

Comment: Not just client applications, but PL/SQL too.
Also, you want to consider what happens when you want to concatenate two columns together (eg to format an address line for an envelope).

Comment: @Tony Andrews, Could you provide examples of what type of client applications will do that?

Comment: @CodeFlava No I cannot

Answer (score 6):

Probably because `Oracle` does not support `VARCHAR(MAX)`.

`VARCHAR` should not be used in `Oracle` at all.

As for now, it's a synonym for `VARCHAR2`, but it may change in future so that it will distinguish between an empty string and a `NULL`.

`VARCHAR` is supposed to do it but doesn't in current versions of `Oracle`, and hence should not be used.

In `Oracle`, maximum length for a `VARCHAR2` is `4000` in `SQL` and `32767` in `PL/SQL`.

For larger values, you should use `CLOB`, but it's very different from a `VARCHAR2`. You should use special methods to access it, etc.

Comment: Since VARCHAR is ANSI SQL92 standart and VARCHAR2 is not, I don't agree "VARCHAR should not be used in Oracle at all." and "... but it may change in future ..." statements.

Comment: @eyazici: From documentation: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/datatype.htm#sthref3784 *To avoid possible changes in behavior, always use the `VARCHAR2` datatype to store variable-length character strings*. Disagreeing with the instruction manual is not a wisest thing to do, but of course it's your choice. If you want to build an `Oracle` application that may break on the next upgrade, using `VARCHAR` is definitely a way to go.

Answer (score 3):

For starters, Oracle doesn't *have* a VARCHAR(MAX) datatype

Reference:

- [Oracle datattypes](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/datatypes.php)