# Why shouldn't I make all my PL/SQL-only VARCHAR2 32767 bytes?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Or should I ?

(The title is inspired by Gary Myers' comment in [Why does Oracle varchar2 have a mandatory size as a definition parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2241238/272735))

Consider the following variables:

```
declare
  -- database table column interfacing variable
  v_a tablex.a%type; -- tablex.a is varchar2
  -- PL/SQL only variable
  v_b varchar2(32767); -- is this a poor convention ?
begin
  select a into v_a from tablex where id = 1;
  v_b := 'Some arbitrary string: ' || v_a; -- ignore potential ORA-06502
  insert into tabley(id, a) values(1, v_a); -- tablex.a and tabley.a types match
  v_b := v_b || ' More arbitrary characters';
end;
/
```

Variable `v_a` is used to interface a database table column and therefore uses a [`%type` attribute](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/type_attribute.htm#LNPLS01352). But if I know the data type is `varchar2` why shouldn't I use `varchar2(4000)` or `varchar2(32767)` that also guarantee the string read from database column will always fit to the PL/SQL variable ? Is there any other argument against this convention except the superiority of `%type` attribute ?

Variable `v_b` is only used in PL/SQL code and is usually returned to a JDBC client (Java/Python program, Oracle SOA/OSB etc.) or dumped into a flat file (with `UTL_FILE`). If the `varchar2` presents e.g. csv-line why I should bother to calculate the exact maximum possible length (except to verify the line will fit into 32767 bytes in all cases so I don't need a `clob`) and re-calculate every time my data model changes ?

There is plenty of questions that covers `varchar2` length semantics in SQL and explains why `varchar2(4000)` is a poor practice in SQL. Also the difference between SQL and PL/SQL `varchar2`-type is well covered:

- [What is the size limit for a varchar2 PL/SQL subprogram argument in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/186403/272735)
- [VARCHAR(MAX) versus VARCHAR(n) in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1668606/272735)
- [Why does Oracle varchar2 have a mandatory size as a definition parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2241238/272735)
- [Why does VARCHAR need length specification?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3156815/272735)
- [What is the default size of a varchar2 input to Oracle stored procedure, and can it be changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4675417/272735)
- [Why using anything else but VARCHAR2(4000) to store strings in an Oracle database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13858562/272735)
- [Why does an oracle plsql varchar2 variable need a size but a parameter does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22050189/272735)
- [Ask Tom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1145132537055) question: *"I work with a modelers group, who would like to define every varchar2 field with the maximum length."*

The only place where I have seen this issue discussed is the points #3 and #4 in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2244755/272735) by APC:

> The database uses the length of a variable when allocating memory for PL/SQL collections. As that memory comes out of the PGA supersizing the variable declaration can lead to programs failing because the server has run out of memory.
>
> There are similar issues with the declaration of single variables in PL/SQL programs, it is just that collections tend to multiply the problem.

E.g. Oracle PL/SQL Programming, 5th Edition By Steven Feuerstein doesn't mention any drawbacks of declaring too long `varchar2` variables, so it can't be a critical mistake, right ?

**Update**

After some more googling I found out that Oracle documentation has evolved during releases:

A quote from PL/SQL User's Guide and Reference 10g Release 2 [Chapter 3 PL/SQL Datatypes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/datatypes.htm):

> Small VARCHAR2 variables are optimized for performance, and larger ones are optimized for efficient memory use. The cutoff point is 2000 bytes. For a VARCHAR2 that is 2000 bytes or longer, PL/SQL dynamically allocates only enough memory to hold the actual value. For a VARCHAR2 variable that is shorter than 2000 bytes, PL/SQL preallocates the full declared length of the variable. For example, if you assign the same 500-byte value to a VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE) variable and to a VARCHAR2(1999 BYTE) variable, the former takes up 500 bytes and the latter takes up 1999 bytes.

A quote from PL/SQL User's Guide and Reference 11g Release 1 [Chapter 3 PL/SQL Datatypes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/datatypes.htm#CIHEDDFG):

> For a CHAR variable, or for a VARCHAR2 variable whose maximum size is less than 2,000 bytes, PL/SQL allocates enough memory for the maximum size at compile time. For a VARCHAR2 whose maximum size is 2,000 bytes or more, PL/SQL allocates enough memory to store the actual value at run time. In this way, PL/SQL optimizes smaller VARCHAR2 variables for performance and larger ones for efficient memory use.
>
> For example, if you assign the same 500-byte value to VARCHAR2(1999 BYTE) and VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE) variables, PL/SQL allocates 1999 bytes for the former variable at compile time and 500 bytes for the latter variable at run time.

But PL/SQL User's Guide and Reference 11g Release 2 [Chapter 3 PL/SQL Datatypes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/datatypes.htm#LNPLS003) doesn't mention memory allocation any more and I fail to find any other information about memory allocation at all. (I'm using this release so I check only 11.2 documentation.) The same holds also for PL/SQL User's Guide and Reference 12c Release 1 [Chapter 3 PL/SQL Datatypes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/appdev.121/e17622/datatypes.htm#LNPLS332).

I also found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1885974/272735) by Jeffrey Kemp that addresses this question too. However Jeffrey's answer refers to 10.2 documentation and the question is not about PL/SQL at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like this is one of the areas where the PL/SQL functionality has evolved over releases when Oracle has implemented different optimizations.

Note this also means some of the answers listed in the OP are also release specific even that is not explicitly mentioned in those questions/answers. When the time pass by and use of older Oracle releases ends (me daydreaming ?) that information will became outdated (might take decades thought).

The conclusion above is backed with the following [quote](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/tuning.htm#BCGEGEEG) from chapter 12 *Tuning PL/SQL Applications for Performance* of *PL/SQL Language Reference 11g R1*:

> **Declare VARCHAR2 Variables of 4000 or More Characters**
>
> You might need to allocate large VARCHAR2 variables when you are not sure how big an expression result will be. You can conserve memory by declaring VARCHAR2 variables with large sizes, such as 32000, rather than estimating just a little on the high side, such as by specifying 256 or 1000. PL/SQL has an optimization that makes it easy to avoid overflow problems and still conserve memory. Specify a size of more than 4000 characters for the VARCHAR2 variable; PL/SQL waits until you assign the variable, then only allocates as much storage as needed.

This issue is no longer mentioned in [11g R2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/tuning.htm#LNPLS012) nor [12c R1](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/appdev.121/e17622/tuning.htm#LNPLS012) version of the document. This is in line with the evolution of the chapter 3 PL/SQL Datatypes.

**Answer:**

Since 11gR2 it makes no difference from *memory use* of point of view to use `varchar2(10)` or `varchar2(32767)`. Oracle PL/SQL compiler will take care of the dirty details for you in an optimal fashion !

For releases prior to 11gR2 there is a cutoff-point where different memory management strategies are used and this is clearly documented in each release's *PL/SQL Language Reference*.

The above only applies to PL/SQL-only variables when there is no natural length restriction that can be derived from the problem domain. If a varchar2-variable represents a [GTIN-14](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Trade_Item_Number) then one should declare that as `varchar2(14)`.

When PL/SQL-variable interfaces with a table column use `%type`-attribute as that is the zero-effort way to keep you PL/SQL-code and database structure in sync.

**Memory test results:**

I run a memory analysis in Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 with the following results:

```
str_size iterations UGA   PGA
-------- ---------- ----- ------
10       100        65488 0
10       1000       65488 65536
10       10000      65488 655360
32767    100        65488 0
32767    1000       65488 65536
32767    10000      65488 655360
```

Because the PGA changes are identical and depend only on `iterations` and not `str_size` I conclude the varchar2 declared size doesn't matter. The test might be too naïve though - comments welcome !

The test script:

```
-- plsql_memory is a convenience package wrapping sys.v_$mystat s and
-- sys.v_$statname tables written by Steven Feuerstein and available in the
-- code-zip file accompanying his book.

set verify off

define str_size=&1
define iterations=&2

declare
  type str_list_t is table of varchar2(&str_size);
begin
  plsql_memory.start_analysis;

  declare
    v_strs str_list_t := str_list_t();
  begin
    for i in 1 .. &iterations
    loop
      v_strs.extend;
      v_strs(i) := rpad(to_char(i), 10, to_char(i));
    end loop;
    plsql_memory.show_memory_usage;
  end;

end;
/

exit
```

Test run example:

```
$ sqlplus -SL <CONNECT_STR> @memory-test.sql 32767 10000

Change in UGA memory: 65488 (Current = 1927304)
Change in PGA memory: 655360 (Current = 3572704)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

$
```

Comment: Do you have a reference or a test case to support the assertion that memory use is the same regardless of declared size in 11gR2 and 12c?  It makes sense that with newer releases Oracle would handle those details automatically, but it would be nice to have some evidence.

Comment: @jonearles Unfortunately I have no test case. My answer is just concluded from the docs. I'm planning to profile some other code soon so I might test this too at the same time.

Comment: @jonearles Memory test results added.

Comment: That's a good test, I did something similar and got the same results.  To really nail this down it'd be great if someone could run the tests on 10g or 11gR1 and get different results.

Comment: Regarding declaring a GTIN-14 as a varchar2(14) this might also be a problem. If you are using Char semantics and the character encoding is utf8 oracle might reserve 14*4 bytes, since each character in UTF8 can be up to 4 bytes. On the other hand if you declare varchar2(14 BYTE) you will run into problems if your character set is utf16, because there each character takes 2 bytes so 14 bytes will not be enough.

Comment: Regarding the memory test what did you store in the str with size 10? If you stored exactly 10 bytes it makes sense that the memory use should be the same. I wonder what happens if you declare a string with 20 bytes and store just 10 bytes in it. Will you get the same result as declaring the same string as varchar2(32767)?

Comment: @Roland About GTIN. That's correct in a general case: `foo(14 char)` works correctly with all character encodings. If you really need to take into account different character encodings the maximum safe value is `floor((2^15-1)/4)` = 8191 as `foo(8191 char)`. However GTIN can only include digits that are single byte in UTF-8 too.

Comment: @Roland About memory test. I see I didn't mention this explicitly as it could be seen from the test script too. I stored exactly the same 10-byte strings in both scenarios: `rpad(to_char(i), 10, to_char(i))` where `i` is the number of current iteration.

Comment: It would be interesting to see the memory consumption with an additional string of size 20(but only store 10 bytes in it). Will oracle then optimize the unused 10 bytes per string away?

Comment: @Roland I think the existing results already answer to your question. The case of max size of 20 bytes is identical to max size of 32767 bytes. You can run the test by yourself too. The code is available in [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/janihur/orasql-ex).

Comment: @user272735 is it really the case? Isn't that the point to see if Oracle does with small varchar2 the same optimization it does with large varchar2(> 3999 byte)?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's because I came of age in the era when the most memory any system had was 48k and then, happy days, up to a full 64k. And it was not virtual, what you allocated is what you got (wyaiwyg) (WAY-WIG?). I see in a lot of younger programmers a tendency to be lazy in their design and hide design flaws by throwing more memory at it.

If we get into the habit of just typing `varchar2(MAX)` whenever we define a string variable, we stop thinking about the length. But sometimes length matters. If we haven't already done so, as soon as we type the `(` then we should stop and put some thought into how big it really needs to be. Does the size matter here? If so, what is a reasonable maximum (or minimum)? This forces us to look beyond the bytes and fields and indexes to the actual "thing" we are trying to work with. That is never a bad idea.

Discipline is hard. We should be developing habits to enforce it whenever we can. Good data and code design is difficult by nature. There are tools and techniques we can use to make it a little easier, but we shouldn't be doing anything just because it is easier. That's the path to the Dark Side and it catches up to us sooner or later.

Comment: All nice and good those philosophies - but that breaks down hard when it touches reality. If you THINK that 500bytes is a reasonable cutoff you can be sure that somebody will try using 512 bytes and your code will come down throwing exceptions once the data no longer fits the variable.
And for PL-SQL (depending on the version) oracle guarantees that after a certain size the variable will be allocated dynamically, so there is no real benefit to declare your variable with a "low" upper bound when you do not know 100% for certain that this value can never be reached.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the same as in any other piece of software: allocating too much memory will decrease performance and likeliness of failing due to the facts it has occupied all memory.

In my opinion, use `%type` as much as possible since it prevents mistakes when changing data type or length, and makes clear what the origin is from that variable.