Oracle DB - Create Table As - causes "ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long"
I found a weird behavior in a stored procedure that works 99% of the time fine for historizing a standardized report into our Oracle Database.
For some reports I get the error ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long. The procedure creates a temporary table with all the data and is adding a composite primary hash key and hashed business key.
If I perform only the SELECT Statement without the CREATE TABLE temp_tbl for a report that causes trouble it works just fine. Are there any known limitation of CREATE TABLE ... AS functionality?
sql_cmd varchar2(32767);

BEGIN
sql_cmd:= 'CREATE TABLE temp_tbl AS (
        SELECT 
            ID_00010, ID_00020, ID_00030, ID_00040,  to_timestamp(ID_00050, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') as ID_00050, ID_00060, [...],
            to_timestamp("PARSER_TIMESTAMP", 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') as "PARSER_TIMESTAMP",
            
            CAST(STANDARD_HASH(
            STANDARD_HASH(
         UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(ID_00010|| ID_00020|| ID_00030|| ID_00040|| ID_00050|| [...])
       || UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(ID_11040|| ID_12000|| ID_13000|| ID_20000|| [...])
       , 'SHA1')
        ||
     STANDARD_HASH(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(ID_20160|| ID_20170|| ID_20180|| ID_20190|| ID_20200|| [...])
       || UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(ID_20680|| ID_20690|| ID_20700|| ID_20710||  [...])
        , 'SHA1')
        ||   
    STANDARD_HASH(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(ID_30780|| ID_30790|| ID_30800|| [...])
       || UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(ID_30980|| ID_30990|| [...])
       || UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(ID_31820|| ID_31830|| [...])
       || UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(ID_32680|| ID_32690|| [...])
       || UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(ID_50710|| ID_50720|| [...])
    , 'SHA1')
    , 'SHA1') as CHAR(160)) as PK_HASH_KEY,
                CAST(STANDARD_HASH(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(id_20000), 'SHA1') as CHAR(160)) as BK_HASH_KEY
            FROM stg_tbl
            )'

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_cmd;
END;

Additional Info

The length of the cmd_sql string is 13969 and should not be cause of the problem as it's static text and works for other reports of the same type.

Due to the concatenation limitation of 4000 characters I split the PK_HASH_KEY generation into multiple "Sub Hash Keys". The sub hash keys for a report that results in the aforementioned error are well below the limit:




Error Message


Error report - ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
ORA-06512: at "DATAENGINEER.LOAD_PROC", line 38 ORA-06512: at
line 2
01489. 00000 -  "result of string concatenation is too long"
*Cause:    String concatenation result is more than the maximum size.
*Action:   Make sure that the result is less than the maximum size.


Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production


use clob see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1668628/5193536#

Divide the problem into smaller problems and solve the smaller problems.
You have a query:
CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT ...

The error is probably in the SELECT ... so try running the SELECT statement not in PL/SQL and without creating a table:
SELECT ID_00010,
       ID_00020,
       ID_00030,
       ID_00040,
       to_timestamp(ID_00050, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') as ID_00050,
       ID_00060,
       -- ...,
       to_timestamp("PARSER_TIMESTAMP", 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') as "PARSER_TIMESTAMP"
FROM   stg_tbl

If that runs (it should) then the problem is in the hashing, so run the concatenation you use for the first hash:
SELECT UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(
         ID_00010
         || ID_00020
         || ID_00030
         || ID_00040
         || ID_00050
         -- || ...
       )
FROM   stg_tbl

Repeat for the next part of the code until you find the part of the code with the problem.
Once you find it then either:

Don't concatenate so many columns together so you do not exceed the limit.
Concatenate them to an EMPTY_CLOB() so that you can exceed the limit for VARCHAR2 (although that may not be appropriate for use with UTL_RAW or STANDARD_HASH - but you could create a function to iterate over the sub-strings of a CLOB and convert them to RAWs and concatenate).


Thanks for the approach and making me aware not to use PL/SQL as the max allocation size is different. I used DBMS_LOB.substr(col_name, 6000) and now it works perfectly well. Also with the standard_hash function. I run some tests and fortunately the hash is identical with UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW and DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR.
